# what is the alternative of using url.action in ajax

Tags: ajax, url, asp.net-mvc-ajax

E.g.

```
@url.Action("Actionname", "ControllerName", new { id=@item.id, @class="test"})
```

I want such a thing in Ajax, like this:

```
@Ajax.action("Actionname", "ControllerName",new { id=@item.id, @class="test"})
```

I tried this, but it did not benefit me:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(".", "DeleteCountry", "Main", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Details" }, new { CountryID =  item.CountryID , @class="fa fa-times"}) @Ajax.ActionLink(".", "EditCountry", "Main", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Details" }, new {CountryID=item.CountryID,@class="fa fa-pencil"})
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net mvc I use both Ajax.BeginForm

```
 @Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",        OnSuccess = "successFunction", ... })
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.id)
    //etc fields you want to send
}
```

and JQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: "GET",
data: { 'id': '@item.id' },
        success: ...
```

});

Think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks man but should i make this for every action is there better solution?

Comment: Sry for being so late, 1st example is used for huge html forms,

2nd one is good for sending additional js data.

So it uses simple Url.Action wrapped in ajax call. 
ps: Url.Action constructs a link for use(string URL), you can use it in forms, href attr or as a js string

Comment: don't matter and Thank you for you effort 
:)